# A non-blocking connection way in kafka

Tags: scala, connection, apache-kafka, consumer

First of all, I'm new on this so may be the explanation of the problem is not accurate.

I have a topic in kafka with some data. With a consumer (written in Scala) I want to connect to the server and consume that information. The problem is that i think that in some executions a consumer doesn't close properly and now it's blocking the reading.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/elodina/scala-kafka/blob/master/src/main/scala/KafkaConsumer.scala) code.

How can i create a non-blocking connection to read from the topic?

If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: kafka client version?

Comment: This is the version: KAFKA-0.8.2.0-1